# google vision API vs google vision online example

Tags: google-cloud-platform, image-recognition, face-recognition, google-cloud-vision

I'm uploading an image from here:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/

where you can drag a local file and run the algos on it

I then use the **exact same** image with the API and I get different results. In particular, in an image where the web version returns 6 faces, returns only 4 on via the API. There are indeed 6 faces.

Why is this? Is there any transformation I can do to the image to get better results maybe?

Comment: May be you need to increase the maxResults count.

Comment: Similar discrepancies in results also occur when using Mobile Vision so I gather the versions each use are different.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cloud Vision API’s best practices for [Image Sizing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/best-practices#image_sizing), a size of 1600 x 1200 pixels is recommended for optimal results with the FACE_DETECTION feature. Moreover, best results are obtained with subjects having reasonable distance between the eyes on the picture.

Concerning your case, I’ve tested the API with the following [image](https://www.sciencenews.org/sites/default/files/main/articles/faces_opener.jpg) and was returned 8 faces upon setting the `max_results` variable to 8. (see [Send a Face Detection Request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/face-tutorial#send_a_face_detection_request) for additional information)